# Why do wifi networks disappear and appear?

Tags: macos, wifi

I have five wifi networks available in my house; all are "Known" and all have a strong signal and fast and work smoothly with my Mac or with an Android smartphone.

As I am now experimenting with another internet service infrastructure provider, I just added three networks, so that seems related. However, there is no channel overlap between these.

I used Inssider for Mac and reviewed the channels, networks, and radios. All seems in order.

But they sometimes disappear and reappear. For example, I can stare at  "Wi-Fi Settings" and see some disappear and reappear a few times in a minute.

Sometimes I click to connect to one of the found networks and get an error

> Could not join "[Network X]", the network could not be found

and that network disappears from the list.

I think it is related to [this report](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/1797bd8/m1_pro_not_connecting_to_wifi_since_sonoma_update/) about the same message in Sonoma. But the proposed fix, deleting the Wifi service and rebooting, does not work.

After several days, it became consistently impossible to connect to several of the network, whereas before it was inconsistent. Nothing has changed in the setup.

How do I avoid this?

Mac Sonoma 14.1.1 (23B81), Mac Pro 2021.

Comment: This only happens with the Mac, not the phone? Then it sounds like a faulty WiFi receiver in the Mac.

Comment: It will keep scanning for WiFi, it is its job to do so

Comment: are they all on same channel

Comment: Thank you. No, not on same channel. Right, not on the Android phone. Could be a faulty receiver, but overall the Wifi works fine. Also, I just added several, so that somehow is related.

Comment: I doubt that the number of networks is an issue. My MacBook doesn't have any problems when there are more than a dozen networks.

Comment: This seems related https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/1797bd8/m1_pro_not_connecting_to_wifi_since_sonoma_update/ But the proposed fix, deleting the Wifi service and rebooting, does not work.